# Comctl32.lib not found migrating old project to VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have an old project named "RoadKill1_1" (from other developer) and I try to compile with VS2019, but it targets Vc7.
The compiler trows this error:

```
LNK1104 no se puede abrir el archivo '..\..\..\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\PlatformSDK\Lib\ComCtl32.Lib'
```

"no se puede abrir el archivo" means: "**File not found**"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have a Visual Studio 2019 installation, the file in `\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\...` probably doesn't exist because why would a 2019 installation have a folder called **Visual Studio .NET 2003**?

Comment: @CyanCoding, this reference comes from the project, which is old.

Comment: You may want to open the project file in a text editor and look for that path. Project files are xml

Comment: At last, I installed an OLD Visual Studio in a VM and I can compile without problems!

Answer (score 1):

`ComCtl32.lib` is contained within the standard library directories for the Windows SDKs (`\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\<Version>\\um\\<Platform>`). Just change the reference from `..\\..\\..\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\\Vc7\\PlatformSDK\\\Lib\\ComCtl32.Lib` to `ComCtl32.lib`. Visual Studio should resolve the DLL automatically based upon the targeted Windows SDK version.